# Separating specific words with underscores, but not the plural form

Tags: regex, shell, sed, sh

I've been working with regex on strings recently and I've hit a snag. You see, I'm trying to get this:

```
chocolatecakes
thecakeismine
cakessurpassexpectation
```

to do this:

```
chocolate_cakes
the_cake_ismine
cakes_surpassexpectation
```

However, when I use this:

```
#!/bin/sh

words_array=(is cake)
number_of_times=0

word_underscorer (){
    echo $1 | sed -r "s/([a-z])($2)/\1_\2/g" | sed -r "s/($2)([a-z])/\1_\2/g"
}

for words_to_underscore in "${words_array[@]}"; do

    if [ "$number_of_times" -eq 0 ]; then
        first=`word_underscorer "chocolatecakes" "$words_to_underscore"`
        second=`word_underscorer "thecakeismine" "$words_to_underscore"`
        third=`word_underscorer "cakessurpassexpectation" "$words_to_underscore"`
    else
        word_underscorer "$first" "$words_to_underscore"
        word_underscorer "$second" "$words_to_underscore"
        word_underscorer "$third" "$words_to_underscore"
    fi

    echo "$first"
    echo "$second"
    echo "$third"
done
```

I get this:

```
chocolate_cake_s
the_cake_ismine
cake_ssurpassexpectation
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You've sort of coded yourself into a corner here if you're relying on just the shell and regex. How can you tell when it's `cake` + some word that just happens to start with `s`, and `cakes` + some word that doesn't start with `s`? For example, `cakesupper`; is it supposed to be `cakes_upper` or `cake_supper`? Both are valid.

Comment: That's a good point, but when I was starting out with this I wasn't thinking of that. I'm not sure what I would do if I started from the ground up though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest having a solid goal that you know is possible to accomplish; then choose the correct tools to accomplish that goal if it's possible. If your goal is just to extract specific words using regex and the shell, then extracting `cake` or `cakes` in word jumbles should be the only goal, not making sure it's "correct" in all use-cases, a sort of intractable problem unless only the extracted words matter. If all you cared about was making sure `cake` or `cakes` is correctly using underscores around them, it's much easier to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've shown you could do something such as:

```
sed -r -e "s/($2)/_\1_/g"  -r -e "s/($2)_s|^($2)(_*)/\1s\2_/g" -r -e "s/^_|_$//g"
```

That should return the final result of:

```
chocolate_cakes
the_cake_ismine
cakes_surpassexpectation
```

The idea here is process by elimination; that is not to say that this method doesn't have potential issues — you'll hopefully understand what I mean below. Each `sed` operation is labeled by number to help you see what is happening.

The `sed` commands work on the array, which starts out with "is" and then "cake":

```
1. is  ->  _is_
2. is_s or is_  ->  iss or is_
3. _is_  ->  is

1. cake  ->  _cake_
2. cake_s or cake_  ->  cakes or cake_
3. _cake_  ->  cake
```

string **one**:

```
1. chocolatecakes -> chocolate_cake_s
2. chocolate_cake_s -> chocolate_cakes_
3. chocolate_cakes_ -> chocolate_cakes
```

string **two**:

```
1. thecake_is_mine -> the_cake_ismine
2. the_cake_ismine -> no change
3. the_cake_ismine -> no change
```

string **three**:

```
1. cakessurpassexpectation -> _cake_ssurpassexpectation
2. _cake_ssurpassexpectation -> _cakes_surpassexpectation
3. _cakes_surpassexpectation -> cakes_surpassexpectation
```

So you can see here what the issue might be with the "is" portion of the array; it could possibly get broken up perhaps in an undesired way during the `sed` operation if somehow it ends up becoming "is_s" on operation number 2. This is where you'll want to test multiple combinations of your strings to ensure that you've covered all the possible scenarios you don't want. Once you've done that you can go back and refine the patterns as needed, or even further find ways to optimize things in a way that allows you to use less piped commands.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work, but I'm still new at this. Could you break down what you're saying in the regexps?

Comment: I've refined the regex even more so; yes I'll add a more detailed breakdown of what is going on.

Comment: Oh I see. This definitely helps out a lot, especially your explanation! I might run into compound words as well, but would regex help in a case like that? I don't know. Still, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the words to a file (`words`) then you can do something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\('$(sed ':l;N;s/\n/\\|/;bl' words )'\)/\1_'/g -e 's/_$//' input
```

This gives you:

```
chocolate_cakes
the_cake_ismine
cakes_surpassexpectation
```

The main point is to construct this sed command:

```
sed -e s/\(chocolate\|cake\|the\|cakes\)/\1_/g -e s/_$// input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\B([^_])\B(cakes?|is)\B/\1_\2/g;s/(cakes?|is)\B([^_])\B/\1_\2/g' file
```

Insert an underscore infront/behind a particular word if the particular word is within another word and the character before/after the particular word is not an underscore.